# User.Identity.Name is null after authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm trying to authenticate user in my ASP.NET MVC application using facebook connect.
I wrote the controller which gets facebook access_token, email of facebook user and then authenticates the user using:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loggedUserEmail, true);
```

after all this I redirect user to the main page where I try to obtain User.Identity.Name to display the name of the logged user (in this case it would be email I guess).
Unfortunately, User.Identity.Name is null.
However, authentication process seems to work as the Request.IsAuthenticated returns true...

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <p>
        @* ###THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION AS User.Identity.Names IS NULL### Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "ChangePassword", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Change password" })!*@ 
        @Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account")
    </p>
}
```

Any ideas why User.Identity.Name isn't initiated?
Thanks,

Bart

P.S.
Instead of

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loggedUserEmail, true);
```

I also tried

```
var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(loggedUserEmail, true);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
// We want to change the expiration of our forms authentication cookie
// to match the token expiration date, but you can also use your own expiration
DateTime expiration = ticket.IssueDate.AddSeconds(facebookTokenExpirationSeconds);
var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name,
                  ticket.IssueDate, expiration, 
                  ticket.IsPersistent, facebookName);

// Encrypt the cookie again
authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);

// Manually set it (instead of calling FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie)
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

but it also doesn't make `User.Identity.Names` contain anything...

Comment: When you stepped through your code what was the value of the `loggedUserEmail` variable that you passed to the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method? Notice that the `Html.ActionLink` throws an exception if the first argument is empty.

Comment: looks like I made quite stupid error and the problem was indeed in loggedUserEmail content... :/ Sorry for not checking it more carefully earlier, would save lots of time. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Could you learn how to format code so we don't have to? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I think, the access token has expired after you redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Identity will be set until the next request is made.  I've worked around this in the past by manually setting the HttpContext.Current.User to an IPrincipal that I created from the Forms Auth ticket after doing the sign in logic.

Something like this (your mileage may vary):

```
var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal
```